# Play Framework, Scala - sending websocket message to the client only if new data available

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket, playframework-2.4

In my play framework application (play 2.4.1) I use WebSocket to send continuous data to the client. At the moment my routine sends a message to the client every 10 sec irrespective of whether new data for the user available.

If no new data available the routine sends an empty string. Reasonably I'll send a message only if new data available. If no new data available a message is not necessary.

How can I do this in Scala?

```
def websocket() = WebSocket.using[String] {

  request =>

    // get session user 
    val user = request.session.get("user") match {
      case Some(s) => s.toString
      case _       => " "
    }

    Logger.info(s"[ap] websocket, client $user connected.")

    val outEnumerator = Enumerator.repeatM[String](Promise.timeout({

      // check for new trigger entry for the user 
      val resultString = Trigger.findByPersonnelNumber(user) match {

        case None =>  ""
        case _    =>  Trigger.delete(user)
                      val orders = Order.findByUser(user)
                      Json.stringify(Json.toJson(orders))
      }
      resultString
    }, 10000))

    (Iteratee.ignore[String], outEnumerator)
}
```

Anything like outEnumerator.ignore[String] if the resultString is empty.

So I be curious for a good solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A direct solution to you problem is to use `Enumeratee.filter`:

```
val outEnumerator = Enumerator.repeatM[String](...) &> Enumeratee.filter[String](s => !s.equals(""))
```

Comment: Great! I don't understand the entire solution just now, but it works very fine. I changed [Int] to [String] in Enumeratee.filter[String]. Thank you very much.

Comment: Enumeratee.filter creates an Enumeratee[E,E] and it will test each chunk of input using the provided predicate and it passes it along iteratee if it statisfies the predicate. You can accept the answer if it's ok for you.